Overriding nerd icons without having to patch fonts repeatedly?
I have a plugin that uses this nerd icon  (a 1 inside a circle), you can search nf-md-numeric_1_circle_outline on nerdfonts.com to see it. I'm on a Mac and want to use Apple's SF Symbols which I think look better, for instance 1.circle instead:

I can paste its text character  into a buffer inside Neovide and it shows without any extra steps or setup. I would also want to replace many other nerd icons with SF Symbols, and could use more elegant an efficient solution than to change icon settings on every single plugin that uses nerd icons, or have to re-patch and reinstall fonts.

Having to do something repeatedly calls for a scripting solution. I can see two ways to accomplish your goal 1) write a script to patch your fonts or 2) replace all occurrences of the character you don't like with the one you like across your configuration settings.
